# How to connect an Amazon EC2 instance to external domain registrar

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

Hello (I'm posting this here because I apparently can't post on amazons forums), I'm new to Amazon AWS and I'm trying to figure out how to make a wordpress site on EC2 (is this the best choice?) and I just want to point it to my registrar (hover.com).

I'm used to setting up sites and pointing domain names on other hosts but AWS is different so I need some help.

For starters, I seem to be constantly directed at using Route53, well that's another AWS service, and it sounds optional, is it really optional? I did a cost estimator for Route 53 and I did 1 hosted zone, with 1000 hits a month and it estimated around $400. That can't be right. I must be missing something. You're telling me for 1000 hits on a particular domain name, I'm going to have to pay $400?

Where's the name servers?

So to give a little history, I setup a wordpress site on an instance of EC2, and I made an elastic IP and connected it to that WP instance. I see a public IP address, great. The public IP address works fine, but I need to find up that domain name I have registered.

I put the public IP address in the DNS settings at hover, but I need the name servers. The only way I was able to get name servers was doing it through Route 53, which again, is this really needed?

I guess all in all, too, is this the right route? Should I be doing an instance of S3 instead of EC2? I'm on the free tier for a year but I'd like to stick with AWS and I don't want to have to change to another host a year form now. I know the elastic IP's is another cost, is this an astronomical cost? Do I even need to setup an elastic IP? I'd assume so. Lots of questions... any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have it working name. I just changed the name servers back to hovers and added the public IP to my DNS entry. Thanks for all the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon route 53 cost pennies to use in most cases, so your estimate is way, way off.

You need to either tell your host registrar that Route53 will handle your DNS for you, by getting the 4 nameservers from Route53 when you setup the domain and entering them onto your domain at your registrar, or assuming your registrar has the ability to do DNS for you, then you don't need route 53 at all. Most registrars will do your DNS for free - even so I prefer to pay the few dollars a month to have it all under one roof, so to speak.

In either case, once you know who is going to handle your DNS, you need to create at minimum a single 'A' record that points your domain name to your EC2 instance IP - there are lots of variations to this, but at its simplest, that is what needs to happen.

Comment: Well, my registrar allows me to enter name servers and an IP address for the @ and * for the A record. But I imagine I can put in that public IP address but unless I know the name servers, that won't work. And it only appears that I can get AWS name servers if I sign up for Route 53. I'm assuming there has to be some name servers available if I'm not using Route 53, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your math is wrong:

> I did a cost estimator for Route 53 and I did 1 hosted zone, with 1000 hits a month and it estimated around $400.

Route53 pricing for zones: $0.50 per hosted zone / month for the first 25 hosted zones

So, 50 cents.

Route 53 pricing for traffic: $0.400 per million queries – first 1 Billion queries / month

So, 0.04 cents.

That's a total of 50.04 cents for a month. It'll take over 60 years to add up to $400 for Route53 DNS at that volume.

I'm having trouble tracking the rest of your question.

Comment: I'm just sharing what the cost calculator showed me when I input those values. It was around $400.00. Not sure why it said that.

Comment: Aha- you entered "1000 queries". Look to the right on that line. The units are *millions*. So you are not making a billion DNS queries per month.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for that; didn't see that. I thought the 1000 queries was 1000  requests to the site a month, not a billion lol.

Answer (score 0):

I did an elastic IP on AWS and bound that to the EC2 instance. I used the public IP on my registrars admin screen and left their existing name servers (hovers) in the name server area.

Answer (score 0):

Ec2 wouldn't be your first choice if you don't expect high loads. For what you will pay with ec2 (starting from like $10 a month) you can have some space in a shared hosting and even your own domain **for a whole year**. Moreover you won't have to deal with DNS because almost all hosting sellers do it for free.

Answer (score 0):

Just to notify others, OP's math was wrong because [AWS calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) counts queries in Millions per month. He likely entered "1000 million queries per month", bringing the estimate to 400

[image]